# Why are there so many thunderbolt messages in kern.log?

Tags: kernel, thunderbolt

In my kern.log, I have hundreds of messages like:

```
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.178378] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: control channel stopped
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.452712] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: control channel starting...
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.452717] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: starting TX ring 0
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.452766] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0x0 -> 0x1)
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.452770] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: starting RX ring 0
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.452780] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1 -> 0x1001)
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.638382] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.638393] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1001 -> 0x1)
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.638407] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
Aug 26 12:28:22 cabron kernel: [11904.638419] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0x1 -> 0x0)
```

They all have the same datestamp (e.g. Aug 26 12:28:22). What is the kernel trying to tell me here?

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo X1 carbon 6th Gen, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you have bugged thunderbolt firmware.

Before march 7th your system would have crashed. There was a [patch introduced](https://lists.01.org/pipermail/thunderbolt-software/2018-March/000055.html) that made this problem die gracefully so the system could continue. The person that tested this patch also got [told by Lenovo](https://lists.01.org/pipermail/thunderbolt-software/2018-March/000056.html) there might be a BIOS update that would fix this but since it is August and not March you might want to report this directly to Lenovo support.

Comment: OP may not have applied BIOS updates. It's usually done within Windows...

Comment: freedos you meant there but still up to Lenovo to supply a method.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the patch and email thread. I have the most recent BIOS (1.27, released on Jul 18) so it seems Lenovo still hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: My Dell's use Windows to flash the BIOS. Lenovo's use of FreeDOS would make life easier for Linux users. +1 for that tidbit :) OP has just commented BIOS is up-to-date so it's time to start nagging the Lenovo folks.

Comment: I upgraded to the most recent firmware (released two days ago) and the problem is no longer there. Thank you!